# Porqué este método no cambia el valor de mi variable?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Antes que nada, SOY NOVATO EN PROGRAMACIÓN ANDROID.

La idea de este método es que pueda validar si el dispositivo ya se ha utilizado anteriormente.

Todo funciona perfectamente, lo único que da error es que el método no le asigna el valor a la variable según el resultado del if.

el DataSnapshot se obtiene de Firebase.

Podría alguien explicarme en qué estoy mal, la estructura del método es la correcta, la variable debe estar declarada en otro sitio o cualquier detalle que no esté permitiendo que mi variable cambie de valor.

La variable es `public boolean validacionDispositivoConGoogle;`, global dentro de la clase.

Aquí está el método :

```
public boolean validarDispositivoConGoogle(final String iDdispositivo, final String emailusuario) {

    final DatabaseReference referenceIDdispositivo = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    referenceIDdispositivo.child(ReferenciasFirebase.NODO_ID_DISPOSITIVO).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot iddispositivos : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (iddispositivos.getKey().equals(iDdispositivo)) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                            "Key: " + iddispositivos.getKey() + " idDispositivo:" + iDdispositivo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (iddispositivos.getValue().equals(emailusuario)) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "el usuario es identico", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        validacionDispositivoConGoogle = true;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "getValue: " + iddispositivos.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Email: " + emailusuario, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "el usuario no coincide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        validacionDispositivoConGoogle = false;
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    referenceIDdispositivo.child(iDdispositivo).setValue(emailusuario);
                    validacionDispositivoConGoogle = true;
                    return;
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return validacionDispositivoConGoogle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo una llamada **"Asíncrona"** para obtener los datos. Esto quiere decir, que los datos que solicitas corren en un hilo diferente al principal para evitar que se bloquee el UI (Interfaz de usuario), al hacer una petición a un API o Servicio Web. Por lo tanto, cualquier operación que esté fuera del hilo que maneja la petición seguirá de manera síncrona.

Tu método sigue la siguiente secuencia **síncrona**:

- Se crea la referencia a la base de datos.
- Se busca el nodo (hijo en firebase) y se activa un listener que permite obtener los datos en tiempo real (cuando ese nodo cambie algun valor).
- Se retorna la variable `validacionDispositivoConGoogle`.

Tu método sigue la siguiente secuencia **asíncrona**:

- Luego de un periodo de tiempo X, llega el valor a **onDataChange**.
- Se procede a ejecutar lo que hay en dicho método del listener.

Si te fijas el método no espera el resultado antes de retornar porque la data llega después de que el método retorna, por lo tanto obtienes el mismo resultado que tiene la variable global al llamar el método. Al final deberías poner el método tipo void porque no vale la pena retornar un valor de esa manera.

Tu solución, es crear un método (le nombras como quieras) de respuesta en el `onDataChange`. Por ejemplo:

```
private void doSomething() { 
    // Aqui ejecutas las operaciones que involucran al valor obtenido 
}
```

Eliminas los `return;` de tu `onDataChange` y al final llamas `doSometing()`. Esto hará que ese método se dispare una vez obtenido el dato desde Firebase y, ejecutes en dicho método, las operaciones correspondientes con tu valor obtenido.

Comment: Tu respuesta ha sido la indicada Andrespengineer. Muchas gracias, he podido resolver el problema