# ¿Error al extraer un dato de Firebase recién agregado Android Studio?

Tags: firebase, null

Tengo dos aplicaciones una donde un cliente tiene que agregar una compra(con todos sus respectivos datos) y la otra app donde el repartidor le aparece en un recyclerview todas las compras echas.

Al abrir la app del repartidor se cargar todas las compras (en esta parte no hay problema) cargar todos los datos que tengo en la base de datos en firebase.

El **problema** que tengo es que cuando el cliente agrega una compra y mi aplicación del repartidor esta abierta sale un error el cual consiste en que 
lee todas las compras que ya estan en la base de datos, **pero** gusto cuando le la compra que se agrego y extraigo toda la informacion de sus childs salen como null y no aparecen los datos al instante y ahi marca un null como **error** sino hasta que abro la aplicacion otra vez, es decir, marca el error se cierra la app del repartidor lo vuelvo a abrir y ahi esta la compra con todos sus datos.

El nuevo pedido que se agrega todos los valores que saca de los childs son null...lugar,fecha,nombre,etc.

> codigo ignoren los logs

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("pedidos");

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(contadorActualizar == 1){
                contadorAgregar++;
            }
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> items = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            String lugar = null;
            String fecha = null;
            String idPedido = null;
            float total = 0;
            boolean flag = false;
            Usuario user = null;

            pedidos.clear();
            while (items.hasNext()) {
                contadorIncial++;
                contadorAgregar = contadorIncial;
                Log.d("TODAS-PEDIDOS","ENTROOOOOOOOO");

                DataSnapshot item = items.next();
                lugar = item.child("lugar").getValue()+"";
                fecha = item.child("fecha").getValue()+"";
                total = Float.parseFloat(item.child("total").getValue()+"");
                idPedido = item.getKey();

                //segunda consulta
                String ruta = idPedido+"/usuario";
                DataSnapshot usuarioSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child(ruta);
                String imagenU = usuarioSnapshot.child("Imagen").getValue()+"";
                String nombreU = usuarioSnapshot.child("Nombre").getValue()+"";
                Log.d("USUARIOOOqqqqwww", "NOMBRE: "+nombreU);
                String telefonoU = usuarioSnapshot.child("Telefono").getValue()+"";
                user = new Usuario(imagenU,nombreU,telefonoU);

                Log.d("TODAS-CONTADOR","------------------------------------------------------------------------" + contadorActualizar + " -> " + fecha + " " + idPedido);
                segundaConsulta(lugar,total,fecha,user,idPedido);

            }

            //flagItem = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

        }});

}



public ArrayList<Articulo> segundaConsulta(final String lugar, final float total, final String fecha, final Usuario userr, String idPedido){

    final ArrayList<Articulo> articuloe = new ArrayList<>();
    mDatabaseArticulos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("pedidos/"+idPedido+"/articulos");
    Log.d("Articulos12", idPedido+"/articulos");
    mDatabaseArticulos.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> items = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            articuloe.clear();
            while (items.hasNext()) {
                Log.d("Articulos12", "------");
                DataSnapshot itemArticulo = items.next();
                int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(itemArticulo.child("cantidad").getValue() + "");
                String detalles = itemArticulo.child("detalles").getValue()+"";
                String especialidad = itemArticulo.child("especialidad").getValue().toString();
                String imagen = itemArticulo.child("imagen").getValue().toString();
                String nombre = itemArticulo.child("nombre").getValue().toString();
                float precio = Float.parseFloat(itemArticulo.child("precio").getValue().toString());
                String idAr = itemArticulo.getKey();


                Articulo articulo = new Articulo(cantidad, detalles, especialidad, idAr, imagen, nombre, precio);
                articuloe.add(articulo);

            }
            Pedido entry = new Pedido(articuloe,lugar,total,fecha,userr);
            pedidos.add(entry);


           // return articuloe;

            crear(pedidos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

        }});

        return articuloe;


}
```

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de código utilizado.

Comment: Ya agrege el codigo

Comment: ¿Puedes especificar exactamente dónde te marca el error de `null`? O mostrar el Logcat del error. También veo que estas intentando retornar una lista `articuloe` en la segúnda consulta de manera síncrona por lo que siempre te devolverá la lista vacía. [Puedes ver esta solución propuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/161760/38154) si lo que quieres es utilizar los valores que obtienes desde Firebase una vez obtenidos.

Comment: En en ese nuevo pedido que se agrega todos los valores que saca de los childs son null...lugar,fecha,nombre,etc.  La parte de artículoe si supuse eso por eso lo comente